# Calling alert inside bootbox

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, bootbox

What I am doing is I am using bootbox popup to insert and update values in a row. So before inserting and updating values I am checking if certain values exists in array or not. For example.

```
if($db_array['updates'] == 'E-mail sent'){
                    echo "<script>
                     alert("cannot send email")
                      </script>";
                }
```

However the alert box is not shown in the screen and the pure script code appears in the ajax response. So if anyone could help me I really appreciate it.

Comment: are you just want to check if values already exists or not in the db and then show an alert?

Comment: while updating or inserting if that value is selected from dropdown then i want to show alert and stop the execution and yes it is all done in bootbox popup.

Answer (score 0):

It apperars that your syntax is wrong. try using the following code:

```
if ($db_array['updates'] == 'E-mail sent') {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("cannot send email");</script>';
}
```

If you have many cases you can use a switch like this:

```
switch ($db_array['updates']) {
case "E-mail sent":
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("cannot send email");</script>';
    break;
case "Something else 1":
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("some different alert");</script>';
    break;
case "Something else 2":
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("some different alert2");</script>';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't help at all. Still the alert box doesn't appear and all script code appears on ajax response in firebug.

Comment: Do you have teamviewer? i cannot fully understand what you trying to do

Comment: what I am doing is simply I have one update button. When it is clicked, a bootbox popup window appears in which I can insert or update values. This popup has a dropdown list such as SMS received, E-mail sent etc. So what i want to do is if E-mail sent is selected from dropdown and tried to update or insert, I simply want to call another alert to display cannot send email and stop the query execution.